# What does std::geometric_distribution do for probability 0?

Tags: c++, statistics

The geometric distribution is degenerate when given a probability parameter 0. C++ includes such a distribution. Does it define the behavior when the probability is 0?

On my machine under gcc the following code outputs `9223372036854775808` (i.e. `1ULL << 63`):

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::mt19937_64 rng(0);
    auto dist = std::geometric_distribution<uint64_t>(0.0);
    std::cerr << dist(rng) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Latest C++ Standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/rand.dist.bern.geo), `geometric_distribution` requires that `p` is **greater than zero** and less than 1.

> `explicit geometric_distribution(double p);`
>
> 2 Preconditions: 0 < `p` < 1.
>
> 3 Remarks: `p` corresponds to the parameter of the distribution.

If you violate this precondition by passing `0` for `p`, you simply have Undefined Behaviour. Anything can happen and your program is simply invalid.

Comment: Oh that's a bit nasty that it's also undefined for p==1. Good to know.